# echo $HOSTNAME result become key to a variable

Tags: bash, shell

Property
server1=abc,def,ghc
server2=xyz,tes,iuy

```
#!/bin/sh

echo $server1
abc,def,ghc

echo $HOSTNAME
server1
```

with those info above, I want to output the output "abc,def,ghc" in a test variable.

```
echo \$$HOSTNAME
$server1

bash-4.1$ test=`echo \$$HOSTNAME`
bash-4.1$ echo $test
8722HOSTNAME
```

How can I get this done in perl/bash?

Comment: Please be so polite to read the two minute [help→tour](http://unix.stackexchange.com/tour) to get familiar with this Q&A site. Especially the part about no chit-chat (click on the "edited .. ago" link to see what was removed as  inappropriate in your post).

Answer (score 5):

`man 1 bash` says:

*If the first character of parameter is an exclamation point (!), it introduces a level of variable indirection.  Bash uses the value of the variable formed from the rest of parameter as the name of the variable; this variable is then expanded and that value is used in the rest of the substitution, rather than the value of parameter itself.  This is known as indirect expansion.*

```
$ server1=abc,def,ghc
$ HOSTNAME=server1
$ echo ${!HOSTNAME}
abc,def,ghc
```

Answer (score 1):

In bash:

```
$ server1=abc,def,ghc
$ HOSTNAME=server1
$ eval "echo \$$HOSTNAME"
abc,def,ghc
```

In Perl (no using strict):

```
$server1 = "abc,def,ghc";
$HOSTNAME = "server1";
print "$$HOSTNAME\n";
```

Both variants are not really nice and cross many borders of clean scripting.